# Is there a way to further optimize this band-pass filter?

Tags: filter, band-pass

Is there a way to further optimize this band-pass filter created by *FilterWizard* so that it completely blocks below 30kHz and above 300kHz?

I played a little with the numbers and found that (in this tool) I was pushing the limits. But maybe you still have an idea – additional components?

This is only for practice purposes. I am not a qualified e-technician.

I would like an input of around 9V. The resulting 8.75V are also OK.

If you want to reproduce it, please note the combobox says *Low Noise*.

I think it won't work due to the physics, right?

[image: magnitude]

[image: circuit]

[image: resulting properties]

Comment: No such thing as an ideal ("brick wall") filter. Everything about designing a filter implies trade-offs. In this case, how much are you willing to attenuate at a certain frequency? In general, the higher the order, the steeper the transition widths, but the higher the noise, the component sensitivity, etc. The steepest are the Cauer/elliptic filters. If pole-zero filters are not possible, the steepest all-pole filter is Chebyshev, in which case you'll have to determine how much ripple in the passband is acceptable. As it is, your question can't be answered, you need proper requirements.

Comment: You can make the curve much steeper if you change the values of R and L.

Comment: @MissMulan Unlikely. As there are no L:s to begin with, and only changing R and C values won't increase the filter order so it would not make the curve any steeper.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention if this is a band pass RC filter or a band pass RLC filter so I assumed it is RLC since they are more common.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  Unfortunately, I still have too little reputation to give +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Having a brick wall filter with infinitely narrow roll-off that requires infinitely many more stages, so it is not physically realizable.

You have to define the frequencies you want to remove and leave and have a finite roll-off slope between pass band and stop band frequencies, and that defines the filter order, i.e. how many stages is necessary to realize it.

The filter already has fourth order low-pass and fourth order high pass. As confirmed by the slider, 8th order Butterworth type response band pass filter.